# do-while loop "enter more (y/n)" - character issue

Tags: c, character, scanf, do-while

So I'm working on basic C skills, and I want to design a code which enters as many numbers as the user wants. Then, it should display the count of positive,negative & zero integers entered.
I've searched Google & StackOverflow. The code seems fine according to those programs.
It compiles & runs. But whenever I input anything after the prompt "enter more? y/n", it returns to the code..
Please have a look at the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int no,count_neg=0,count_pos=0,count_zero=0;
    char ch='y';
    clrscr();
    do
    {
        puts("Enter number");
        scanf("%d",&no);
        if (no>0)
            count_pos++;
        else if (no<0)
            count_neg++;
        else
            count_zero++;
        puts("want more? - y/n ");
        scanf("%c",&ch);
    }
    while (ch=='y');

    if (ch=='n')
    {
        printf("No of positives = %d",count_pos);
        printf("No of negatives = %d",count_neg);
        printf("No of zeros = %d",count_zero);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's reading the newline that terminated the number input.

Comment: Instead of using `scanf`, use `fgets()` to read a line of input, then use `sscanf()` to parse it. Otherwise, you'll run into lots of problems due to input left in the stream, or fields that don't parse properly.

Comment: If you want to input lines (and you do), don't mess about with characters, input _lines:_ see http://powerfield-software.com/?p=65.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with "scanf("%c", &ch);"

What happens actually is :
 Suppose you enter 'y' as a choice and hit 'enter'(return), the return is a character and
 its character value is 10(since its a new line character), thus the scanf takes the 'return'
  as its input and continues.

Solution : 
1. use getchar() before scanf()

// your code

```
  getchar();  
  scanf();
```

//your code
getchar() takes the return value as its input, thus you are left with your actual value.

1. add '\n' to scnaf()
   // code
    scanf("\n%c", &ch);
   //code

when scanf() encounters the '\n' character it skips it (google about scanf, to know how
 and why ), thus stores the intended value inside 'ch'.

Answer (score 0):

A "better" form for:

```
int main()
```

is:

```
int main(void)
```

**clrscr** is not standard C.

You ought to check the return-value of any function which might indicate "interesting status," such as a failure condition, and from which you can gracefully deal with the situation.  In this case, **scanf** is such a function.

I believe that your first **do ... while** condition will become false because it will pick up the *newline* character following your first **scanf** call.  You might want to read about **getchar** or **getc**, instead of using **scanf** for the task of checking whether or not to run the loop again.  You can "eat" unwanted characters, including a *newline*.

Comment: actually `int main()` is better practice as it valid both in C and in C++, `int main(void)` is only valid in C.

Comment: Evan Dark: Disagree: That strikes me as encouraging thinking of C and C++ as "close enough."  They are different languages and treating them otherwise seems to be the cause of countless misunderstandings, as observed in various C support-forums.  Besides that, while **int main()** is acceptable in C because the definition results in an implicit no-parameter specification[frex C99:6.7.5.3p14], C99:5.1.2.2.1p1 (frex) doesn't explicitly mention it.  (Some people might argue about that latter point and others might not.)  But opinions differ, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have corrected the problem. The problem was this that the "enter" you press after each number is a character and is takenup by the scanf() as it is there to scan some characters. So I have added a `getchar();` before the `scanf();`so the "enter" is taken up by `getchar();` and scanf() is now free to take your input.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main() 
  {
      int no,count_neg=0,count_pos=0,count_zero=0;
      char ch='y';
      clrscr();
      do
       {
         puts("Enter number");
         scanf("%d",&no);
         if(no>0)
         count_pos++;
         else if(no<0)
         count_neg++;
         else
         count_zero++;

         puts("want more? - y/n ");
         getchar();//<---- add this here 
         scanf("%c",&ch);
        }
        while(ch=='y');

    if(ch=='n')
    {
     printf("No of positives = %d",count_pos);
     printf("No of negatives = %d",count_neg);
     printf("No of zeros = %d",count_zero);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

To fix the input is to use a C String like this scanf("%s",...);

This might break if you input more than one character because scanf will keep reading until the user hits enter, and your ch variable is only enough space for one character.

Comment: **puts** and **printf** would affect **stdout** and not **stdin**, which is what **scanf** uses.

Comment: actually don't. `%s` is a very dangerous and error prone thing to use in `scanf`, as it doesn't take the size of the buffer into account, and can overflow it. Also it only reads a single word. use `fgets` to read a line full line safely, or `%*s`

Answer (score -1):

I run your code in Online compiler. I am not sure about other compiler.

I slightly changed your code. i.e., first i read char then int. If i do not change the order, **char variable holds int variable value**. This is the reason ( ch variable holds values of no variable).

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main() 
 {
  int no,count_neg=0,count_pos=0,count_zero=0;
  char ch='y';

  do
   {
     puts("Enter number");
     scanf("%c",&ch);
     scanf("%d",&no);
     if(no>0)
     count_pos++;
     else if(no<0)
     count_neg++;
     else
     count_zero++;
     puts("want more? - y/n ");        
    }
    while(ch=='y');
    if(ch=='n')
    {
     printf("No of positives = %d",count_pos);
     printf("No of negatives = %d",count_neg);
     printf("No of zeros = %d",count_zero);
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

EDIT: 
        whenever integer and char are read through keyboard. it stores int value and enter key value. so this is the reason.

You have to add

```
scanf("%d",&no);
you code
......
.....
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c",&ch);
```

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
ch = getche();
```

instead of:

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

Comment: Also, add #include <conio.h>